# Excel VBA URL hyperlink in RichText email body

Tags: email, excel, outlook, excel-2013, vba

Does anyone know how to create a RichText email body, that has a URL bookmark in it?

For example, here is my code:

```
Sub SendEmailUsingWord()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim strBody As String

' The body of the message, want to create a hyperlink to (e.g.) http://www.google.com but
' still display HERE.
' In HTML it would be <a href="http://www.google.com">HERE</a>
' But I want to achieve this in a Rich Text email

strBody = "Please click HERE to be fantastic!" & vbNewLine

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With olEmail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
    .Display

    .To = "someone@someone.com"
    .Subject = "Email Subject"

    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor

    wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore strBody
    '.send
End With
End Sub
```

Many thanks for your help :)
Dave

Comment: Do you specifically want RTF or it can be HTML as long as you get a link?

Comment: Hi Dmitry. I would like to use RTF, but if it's far too complicated then I'll have to convert the code over to using HTMLbody instead.

Comment: You can still use RTF, but you would need to work with the RtfBody property or use the Word Document object. What was wrong with your code above?

Comment: There isn't anything *wrong* with my code, I just didn't know how to add the URL in the strBody, so that it would come up as a hyperlink in the email body when the email was generated. A code sample would be handy..... :)  The commented code explains what I'm trying to achieve.  Thanks.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Could this be what I'm looking for? `Object.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor, Address, SubAddress, ScreenTip, TextToDisplay, Target)` where Object would be the word document object?

Answer (score 2):

After Dmitry pointing me in the right direction, I tried the following code:

`wdDoc.Hyperlinks.Add wdDoc.Range, "http://www.google.com", , , "HERE"`

and it has solved my problem!

I wasn't considering the `word.document` object when creating the email body, when I should have been. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

There's small change in your code.

You need to add **BODYFORMAT** as

```
.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
```

After setting **BODYFORMAT**, set the **HTMLBODY** of the Email.

```
 .HTMLBody = "<HTML><H2>The body of this message will appear in HTML.</H2><BODY>Type the message text here. </BODY></HTML>"
```

Check this link for complete example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869979(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thank you Paresh. Unfortunately, I'm looking to have the mail body only in Rich Text format, as I will be pasting in some cells (which have been formatted) from other parts of the spreadsheet.  Otherwise, I'd do it all in HTMLbody, but need to know if it's possible to do what I'm trying in RTF body.